# image OnMouse popout from container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onmouseover

I am making a website where I am placing an "ad" which I want to hide under the container div,  but you can still see the tip of it. when you take your cursor over it I want it to smoothly come out from underneath the container. And when you remove the cursor i would want it to go back to it`s first position under the container. Anyone know a simple css, a jquery, or a javascript I can use?

Thanks!

**Edit**

Thanks for all the responses!
I am sorry if I just didn't get it, or if I was a bit unclear in my question, but i want the image to smoothly move horizontally from behind the my container on the right side to where my background is. so I want it to move and not just pop right out. So i basically want my picture to smoothly move back and fourth from underneath the container. When I place the cursor over the tip of the picture i want it to slowly move out from it's position under the container, and when i let go i want it to slowly go back. I see now that my title was a bit misleading, I'm sorry.
Hope someone can help me!

Comment: I found a code! 
using this:

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".menu_option").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".menu_option").animate({left:'50px'});
  });
  $(".menu_option").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".menu_option").animate({right:'50px'});
  });
  $('.menu_option').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.menu_option').animate({left : 0});
});
});

</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#demo").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
var str = "background-color:red;  height: 100px; width: 100px";
$(this).attr("style", str);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
var str = "background-color:red;  height: 10px; width: 10px";
$(this).attr("style", str);
    }
});
});

</script>

<div id="demo" style="background-color:red;  height: 10px; width: 10px"> <br/><br/><br/></div>
```

Comment: woah, interesting .on syntax! Found it: http://api.jquery.com/on/#example-6 - I would however use .css rather than attr style

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method:

```
$("#demo").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color', 'red'}).height(100).width(100);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color', 'red'}).height(10).width(10);
    }
);
```

Comment: That is identical in functionality to the one posted 10 minutes ago by @Uday - however I believe your CSS syntax is wrong. Either (prop,val) OR ({prop:value})

Answer (score 0):

This was fun

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zP566/)

**Script**

```
$(function() {
  $("#demo").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css({
            "height": "100px",
            "width": "100px"
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css({
            "height": "10px",
            "width": "10px"
        });
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#demo {
    background-color:red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#main {
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo">This is an ad</div>
<div id="main">Here is a div</div>
```